# LinearSVC() не дает нужный результат в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook, sklearn, jupyter-lab

Всем привет, я работаю с Jupyter онлайн и в приложении на компе.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
X_text = []
y = []
for intent, intent_data in BOT_CONFIG["intents"].items():
    for example in intent_data["examples"]:   
        X_text.append(example)
        y.append(intent)      
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="char", ngram_range=(3,3))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_text)
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Этот кусок кода должен выдавать : `LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000, multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)`

Но выдает он это только в онлайн Jupyter, а локально на компе он выдает только :  `LinearSVC()`
Я уже устанавливала все пакеты и обновляла(sklearn, kernel)
Не понимаю почему на компе не дает правильный вывод, потому прошу помощи
Заранее спасибо)